# Karate-gatling: set local addresses

Tags: karate

I have simple karate feature file for testing an API, and I want to use this feature file for load testing. Thus I am using Gatling to execute the karate feature file: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling

However, when I fire up multiple users, I want to submit the requests with different ip alias that I have configured.

Using Gatling, I could use localAddress to bind to the socket

```
val protocol = http.localAddresses(ip)
```

But in Karate-Gatling, karateProtocol is used instead

```
val protocol = karateProtocol()
```

And the readme states that "Karate is responsible for making HTTP requests while Gatling is only measuring the timings and managing threads".

This means that the HTTP requests and localAddress bindings cannot be changed through Gatling, but I am wondering if there is a workaround through Karate so that different ip alias can be used for different requests.

Comment: we have implemented support for local addresses in this commit: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/1b39f26622c482757464888682330ab425db83a0 - can you help test this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a feature request is needed to tell the HTTP client (Apache for e.g.) to use a local-address.

It would be great if you can help contribute and test, one way to set the localAddress would be in the code [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-apache/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/apache/ApacheHttpClient.java#L156):

```
    RequestConfig.Builder configBuilder = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec(LenientCookieSpec.KARATE)
            .setConnectTimeout(config.getConnectTimeout())
            .setSocketTimeout(config.getReadTimeout());
    String localIp = "1.2.3.4";
    try {            
        InetAddress localAddress = InetAddress.getByName(localIp);
        configBuilder.setLocalAddress(localAddress);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.logger.error("failed to resolve local address: {}", localIp);
    }
```